# Mass Emailing API? (EmailBlast)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, email

We have a project coming up where I want to create a webservice (EmailBlast) that will talk to our 3 or 4 intranet apps. These intranet apps will make webservice calls to EmailBlast informing EmailBlast of the emails that need to be sent out. I will have a simple Approval workflow so that when a request comes in I will notify admins and request thier approval before sending the emails.

So rather than do the entire project myself I was wondering if there is a Email API that can queue up emails, create reports on bounce backs etc..  And then I would wrap all that up with my Workflow stuff and web services to communicate with my intranet apps.

Is there something like that out there? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: How internal do the mails need to be? Sendgrid.com is quite amazing, has a full API but would be an external service (and would charge based on the mail). Not sure if this meets your requirements.

Comment: I mean the internal apps communicate with each other..

The actual emails would be sent to external agencies (I work for DOJ and we need to send out emails to inform agencies that they are late , etc.. ) 

Being charged by the email.. Id have to see if the higherups would be ok with that. I doubt it though

Comment: Sendgrid is likely so cheap that it wouldn't even move the needle (depending on your requirements) - 200/day is free, 10k a month is $10.

Comment: Good point. I guess we would send out about 1000 a day.. so its not a big deal.. I just don't know being a gov agency if they are ok using a external mail server... Im just a lowly coder surrounded by toner cartriges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the SOAP API for [Lyris Listmanager](http://www.lyris.com/solutions/listmanager/). It is an excellent product. Sending out emails is no trivial task. You need things like [domain keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_keys), [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) etc or your emails will end up in the junk mail box, or you can easily be [blacklisted](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx).  You don't want this to happen to your corporate sendmail.

Also [automated bounce handling](http://www.lyris.com/solutions/listmanager/compare-feature-sets/) is a huge time saver. You can have the system retry after x number of times, and remove from the list if you want.

Most commercial email management systems will handle this for you. Listmanger is one of the few stand alone email management systems that you can install locally and start using it. Check out the free trial, it will save you alot of headache down the road.

Comment: its not clear to me.. does the API come with all levels of ListManager? If the app is internal how do you charge per email ?  Or is it a one time charge? 

Looking at the API PDF now.

Comment: You just pay a one time fee for it and you can send as many emails as you want. The different licensing levels only restrict features, and # of emails you can send per hour.

Answer (score 1):

MailChimp offers a great mass-mailing service and has an API for it.  However, it's an external service, not something you can install internally.

There are also hardware systems that you can install internally that do this sort of thing.  Google "mail appliance".

Comment: After more research it seems all the system I find are external... makes sense since its easier to make money charging for the use of thier email servers..

But we already have a email server so we just need a pay once type of thing it seems.. perhaps its really not a big deal for me to do this manually. ?